# How to communicate between Silverlight and desktop application?

Tags: .net, silverlight, inter-process-communicat

I have **in-browser** Silverlight 5 application. Need to make it work with scanners. I have control over SL5 app and I can develop desktop application (.NET) to do scanning part.

How can I make SL application "talk" to desktop application? Ideally I see it as following:

1. My "document management" works as is in SL5 when you just upload/download documents.
2. When user want's to scan - SL5 initiates some process(?) that causes desktop app to open.
3. If there is no application on desktop - it would transfer to web page with instructions and download.
4. When desktop application opens - SL application will pass paramters, settings, etc.
5. When document scanned - desktop application will pass information back to SL application

Is there any way to make SL/WPF talk to each other? How?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented scanning in a silverlight application before.  It involved creating an activex / dll control and hosting it next to the silverlight application in the hosting .aspx page.  The control itself was completely hidden, i just used it's methods to access the scanner and work with the local file system.  Now granted, I had to make this a trusted site and what not to allow the control to access the client computer.  then you can use javascript as the bridge between the silverlight code and your scanning control.  To pass the image back to Silverlight, I just converted the scanned image to a base64 string and passed it back to the javascript and on to the silverlight code, which then ultimately passed it back to the server and into an image repository.

Comment: Like I mentioned - I got it working already in a much cleaner (IMO) way. Silverlight calls twain.dll via P-Invoke directly. No ActiveX, no JavaScript. Only elevated permissions required. All works "natively" I get bitmap byte array from twain driver and convert it to TIFF on a fly.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to "see" the scanner from the app server? I have had success with printing by calling a WCF service hosted on the same site as my Silverlight app and getting it to send off the document. You need to manage a table linking users to devices. This might mean you dont need a desktop application at all, but can put that functionality in your Silverlight application. Obviously it is not ideal from a performance viewpoint if you are passing large images around or have a lot of users. However on the server you have the full .net functionality to work with, which makes things pretty simple.

So essentially the UI of your desktop app is in Silverlight and the guts are back on the server.

If you find a direct way to do this I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Seems like I got it.. Not application talking to each other - but my main taks can be accomplished direct from SL. There is twain.dll and P-Invoke in SL which should take care of scanning without any installs.